# How to split a pcap file based on IP Address on RedHat

Tags: pcap

On my linux server I have a huge `pcap` trace file. I need to split this file  based on some specific IP Address.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To read an existing pcap file and output to a new one, based on IP address, use this syntax.

```
tcpdump -r old-pcap-file -w new-pcap-file-for-1.2.3.4 host 1.2.3.4
```

From the [tcpdump man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)

```
-r file   Read packets from file
-w file   Write the raw packets to file rather than parsing and printing them out.
```

Comment: Would you please reformulate this as an answer and not as a comment? I would advise explaining what -r does too.

Comment: for multiple IP Address, what will be the command?

Comment: Also can you please tell me how do i create the same file name for the filtered pcap file. Because i am going to give this command on a while process.

Comment: not sure what you mean, regarding same filename for filtered pcap file

Comment: for multiple ip addresses, i heartily recommend reading the fine man page. (it's still there, at http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html ) `tcpdump -r old-pcap-file -w new-pcap-file host 1.2.3.4 or host 5.6.7.8` and so on.